# Check files on remote computers for time stamp older than X hours and export results to CSV

Tags: powershell, time, export

We are trying to run a script against a pile of remote computers to check the date stamps of files in a fixed folder that are older than say 12 hours and return the results to a CSV.  The date range needs to be flexible as its a set time of 6pm yesterday which will move as the time moves on.

```psh
$computers = Get-Content -Path computers.txt  
$filePath = "c:\temp\profile"
$numdays = 0
$numhours = 12
$nummins = 5   
function ShowOldFiles($filepath, $days, $hours, $mins)
{
    $files = $computers @(get-childitem $filepath -include *.* -recurse | where {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days).AddHours(-$hours).AddMinutes(-$mins)) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)})
    if ($files -ne $NULL)
    {
        for ($idx = 0; $idx -lt $files.Length; $idx++)
        {
            $file = $files[$idx]
            write-host ("Old: " + $file.Name) -Fore Red
        }
    }
}

Write-output $computers, $numdays, $numhours, $nummins >> computerlist.txt
```

Comment: What exactly is the reference time? Always 6 p.m. of the previous day? Always 12 hours before now? Something else?

Comment: The ref time is basically 6pm 28 April 2015  but when we reschedule a job we want to change that time to the rescheduled time.  @Chard's code gets me the info in a sort of way.  I need to just output the machines that DONT have the updated files. At the moment its returning all machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the follow script on all of your remote machines:

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path computers.txt  
$logFile = "\\ServerName\C$\Logfile.txt"

$date = "12/03/2002 12:00"
$limit = Get-Date $date

$computers | %{
    $filePath = "\\$_\C$\temp\profile"

    $files = $null
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Recurse -Force | `
                Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $limit }

    If($files -ne $null){
        "-------------------------[$($_)]------------------------">> $logFile
        $files | Foreach {$_.FullName >> $logFile}
    }
}
```

This will check the folder given (`$filePath`) for files that are older than the limit given. Files older than the limit will have there full file path logged in the given network location `$logFile`.

Comment: unfortunately wirth 1700 machines running them on the remote machine is not practical. we can generate a list of Machines into a TXT file and need to run this PS from a specific machine in that right Vlan.

Comment: You can still use that script. You will just have to write a script to remotely run it on all of the machine from a server.

Comment: running the script is the problem.  we cant seem to get scripts to remote run on the machines. (UAC and GPO prevents this) I am hoping of more of a query to those machines would generate the csv.

Comment: OK as long as you can run the script form a high level account that can access all of the machine C: drives using a path such as `\\MachineName\C$`, and that the list of machines is Domain names then the edit I have made should now work.

Comment: ok put in a the server name and run the script  gettign an OP_MODULUS error.  dont i need to put in a comand into the 'code' [$($_)] part

Comment: Yeah I missed a `|` after the `$computer`, I added it in a min ago. The part `"-------------------------[$($_)]------------------------">> $logFile` is purely to split up the log file by machine name as it will just be one massive list of file apths.

Comment: Thanks
now getting file oipen failure so trying a different location

Comment: That is working.  I now am going to play about with formatting of the log file so we can manipulate it in excel.

Comment: ok due to the files in the folder having some before and some after the date i am gettign rturns on all the machines.  i only one them that dont have files newer than the time limit.   i have amended the filepath to a single file to weed this out but still returning machines that dont fit the query.

Comment: Try the edit, should only log the machine if a file has been see to be old than the date. I have also updated the date selection process to make it easy to add in a date, rather than selecting hours, days and minutes just type in the date/time.

Answer (score 0):

with a small alteration to @chard earlier code I managed to get a workable solution.
The output log file only returns the files that are older than the date in the code.
this can be manipulated in Excel with other outputs for our needs.

I will try the updated code above in a bit.

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\computers.txt"
$logFile = "\\SERVER\logs\output.txt"

$numdays = 3
$numhours = 10
$nummins = 5  

$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$numdays).AddHours(-$numhours).AddMinutes(-$nummins)

$computers | %{
    $filePath = "\\$_\C$\temp\profile\runtime.log"

    Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Recurse -Force | `
                Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } |  
                foreach {"$($_)">> $logFile}
}
```

Comment: found another issue we need to adapt the script to find.  any machines that DONT have the log file need to be listed too.